# Does Hong Kong really have "...significantly more autonomy than other parts of the PRC" in 2022? If so, how exactly?

Tags: china, hong-kong, local-autonomy

[This answer to *Does Hong Kong participate in PRC's decision-making process?*](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/76321/16047) was (probably too) quickly accepted considering the complex and translucent<sup>1</sup> nature of "PRC's decision-making process" (the question) and what "autonomy" means (the answer) in Hong Kong.

The answer begins with the sentence:

> Hong Kong is a Special Administrative Region and so has significantly more autonomy than other parts of the PRC.

The "and so" in this sentence seems to suggest both that Hong Kong has "significantly more autonomy" than PRC and that *this comes from* it being an [Special administrative regions of China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_administrative_regions_of_China) i.e. "if SAR then autonomy".

I used to think that the "A" in SAR was for "autonomous" but no, it's for "administrative". Here's a blurb from Investopedia's [Special Administrative Region (SAR)](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/special-administrative-region.asp):

> Two important SARs are Hong Kong and Macau (also spelled Macao), a pair of relatively autonomous regions within the People's Republic of China that maintain separate legal, administrative, and judicial systems from the rest of the country.

Of course things in Hong Kong have changed in the last few years and I'd like to focus on the extent to which it is still able to "maintain separate legal, administrative, and judicial systems". Yes, separate faces, separate buildings, separate geographic locations, but physically separate has never in history meant *a priori* autonomous or independent.

So I'd like to ask:

**Question:** Does Hong Kong really have "...significantly more autonomy than other parts of the PRC" in 2022? If so, how exactly?

---

<sup>1</sup>definitely not transparent but I'm not qualified to certify it as opaque.

Comment: Apparently,  "than other parts of the PRC"

Comment: It's still "more autonomous", but not as autonomous as it was several years ago. Beijing is trying to make it more like the rest of China, but it's hard to take away freedoms all at once.